# How does recalibration and rank promotion work in Dota 2 Season 4?

Tags: dota-2

I was about 4,900 mmr in Season 3 in my support MMR but I believe I lost at least 7 games out of 10 and only ended up in 4,700 mmr for Season 4. I was told that you lose -75 for every loss and gain +75 for every win in recalibration, but this doesn't seem to be true. However, I calibrated in Ancient 5 from Divine 4.

Then I decided to play my core recalibrations and ended up winning 9 games out of the 10. Then I jumped from Ancient 5 to Divine 2 (With 15% to the next rank). I was initially around 4,700 or 4,800 but i'm now 5,250 MMR. However, I was only around 5k when I hit Divine 4 last season, i'm wondering why I am only Divine 2 this season--but I would guess it has definitely something to do with the distribution of players and their MMRs. Also I noticed that every win will give me around 20% increase on my progress to the next rank.

So my estimate is that:

Divine III - around 5,350

Divine IV - around 5,450

Divine V - around 5,550

Divine VI - around 5,650

Divine VII - around 5,750

Immortal - 5,850 and above

I have been looking at some data online, but the numbers do not seem accurate to determine what MMR you need to reach each rank, but since the progress % is always about 20% per win, then it should make sense that the MMR required to reach a certain rank should be readily easy to calculate. But since I have only me as a data point, I cannot say if this is true for all.

Answer (score 1):

## Recalibration

It is not possible to know exactly how many mmr you got from each calibration/recalibration match as that value is hidden. However, many people have speculated it to be between 50-75. If you've lost 7 out of 10 calibration games i.e. 4 net losses, and lost 200 mmr, that would leave you with `-50` per loss in your recalibration, which would still fall into the anecdotal range.

## Ranks

Ranks are based on player percentages, not a specific mmr. As such, towards the end of a season, it is generally easier to achieve a higher rank even if you did not play any game recently, due to the inflation in mmr. **That's the reason why you will never find an accurate estimate unless it is updated at least weekly.**

For example, in Season 3, I calibrated at Ancient 3 during the start of the season. Towards the end of the season, I played and lost exactly one game but I got promoted to Ancient 6. This is because the average level of the players at Ancient 3 have dropped and my mmr is closer to that of an Ancient 6 at the end of the season, compared to that at the start.

Also, there was a change to stars per rank around October. Now that there are only 5 stars per rank, players have been pushed up accordingly. I recalibrated at Ancient 5 at the start of Season 4, but after that rank update I was moved to Divine 1 despite not having played any game.